# ssh timing out on second login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ssh-keys, puma, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to set up Rails on my site via ssh. When everything is set up, I start the server with `rails server` and I get:

> => Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   Puma starting in single mode...
>   * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
>   * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
>   * Environment: development
>   * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
>   Use Ctrl-C to stop

It would be fine if the issue didn't stop there, but when I point my browser at the IP address on port 3000, my browser just hangs instead of displaying the Rails smoke page.

Since I can't type in more commands, I open a new terminal and log in via:

`ssh -i /path/to/cloud.key user_name@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`

I think I've seen it work before, but now it's timing out:

> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out

I found similar problems resolved on stackoverflow, but none of them solved the problem for public key authentication and when I try their solutions (`ssh user_name@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`), I turn up `Permission denied (publickey).`

So, I want to either learn why my browser is hanging (if I need to install nginx or apache2 or configure puma, etc.), and/or why my attempts to log into a second ssh session are failing.

Any help for this one?

Ubuntu Server 16.04

Rails 5.0.1

Ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question). Stack Overflow's answer acceptance mechanism takes care of identifying answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point your browser to the ip because the server is binding to localhost. You must enter `rails s -b0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still can't see the smoke test page for rails 5.  I'm getting told that the server where the page is located isn't responding.  Any suggestions for that one?

Comment: Could you tell me please, which is the correct port?  Should I be using port 80, port 3000, and so on?  What I have done to date is to use port 3000 and then to check for a response, I used my browser to check x.x.x.x:3000.

Comment: Every port is OK, but you need to setup the firewall to allow the connection.

Comment: I have ufw set to allow 3000/tcp.  Still no luck. Any other ideas?  I'm really stumped.

Comment: Also: I tried port 80 with Puma and had an error return. This is with ufw configured to allow tcp on port 80

Comment: Environment: development * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:80 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: You must use sudo for binding to some ports such as 80.

Comment: So I have an error message that says sudo: puma: command not found.  I did manage to get my server to work however by setting up nginx and configuring it as a reverse proxy to broadcast from port 3000 over port 80. I'm still a bit confused about why the Puma server on port 3000 still times out since I had configured the firewall to allow http requests on port 3000.  Seems strange to me, but whatever. I think nginx might be an advantage for my situation anyways because I want to host multiple domains/websites from the same IP address.

Comment: If you use rvm you should use rvmsudo.